# Read 100 parquet files from s3 parallelly using sc.parallelize() and create a data frame in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have 100 parquet files in s3 bucket, I need to read all those parquet files parallelly by using sc.parallelize() method by creating RDD to increase the performance.

I have created list with all the s3 files base path and passing all paths to sc.parallelize() method, please let suggest how can we achieve this parallelism.

Comment: why do you want to use `sc.parallelize()`. `spark.read` is probably better.

Comment: I am not sure, how spark.read works, is it does the reading of files parallelly. I have more than 100 files in different directories of my s3 bucket.  could you suggest some best way to do that

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using a file list to read into a dataframe.

```
import sys

from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

inputFile = "../data/jsonformatdata.json"

inferredScheme = StructType([
    StructField('events',
                ArrayType(
                    StructType([
                        StructField('entities', ArrayType(StringType(), True), True),
                        StructField('event_name', StringType(), True),
                        StructField('event_properties', ArrayType(StringType(), True), True),
                        StructField('event_timestamp', DateType(), True)]), True), True)])


inputFileList = [inputFile] * 10  # this creates list of 10 files just to show a list of files can be read as well.
print(inputFileList)

initialDF = sqlContext.read.schema(inferredScheme).option("multiline", "true").json(inputFileList)
initialDF.show(n=100, truncate=False)
initialDF = initialDF.select(F.explode(F.col("events")).alias("temp_alias"))
initialDF.show(n=100, truncate=False)

ans_df = initialDF.withColumn("event_name", F.col("temp_alias.event_name"))
ans_df = ans_df.withColumn("event_properties", F.col("temp_alias.event_properties"))
ans_df = ans_df.withColumn("entities", F.col("temp_alias.entities"))
ans_df = ans_df.withColumn("event_timestamp", F.to_timestamp(F.col("temp_alias.event_timestamp"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))

ans_df = ans_df.drop("temp_alias")
ans_df.show(n=100, truncate=False)


ans_df = ans_df.withColumn('mapped', F.map_from_arrays('event_properties', 'entities'))
ans_df.show(n=100, truncate=False)

ans_df = ans_df.select("event_name", F.explode('mapped').alias('event_properties', 'entities'), "event_timestamp")
ans_df.show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Final Output :

```
+----------+----------------+---------+-------------------+
|event_name|event_properties|entities |event_timestamp    |
+----------+----------------+---------+-------------------+
|start     |property1       |entityI  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property2       |entityII |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property3       |entityIII|2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyA       |entityW  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyB       |entityX  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyC       |entityY  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyD       |entityZ  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property1       |entityI  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property2       |entityII |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property3       |entityIII|2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyA       |entityW  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyB       |entityX  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyC       |entityY  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyD       |entityZ  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property1       |entityI  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property2       |entityII |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property3       |entityIII|2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyA       |entityW  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyB       |entityX  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyC       |entityY  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyD       |entityZ  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property1       |entityI  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property2       |entityII |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property3       |entityIII|2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyA       |entityW  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyB       |entityX  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyC       |entityY  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyD       |entityZ  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property1       |entityI  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property2       |entityII |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property3       |entityIII|2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyA       |entityW  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyB       |entityX  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyC       |entityY  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyD       |entityZ  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property1       |entityI  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property2       |entityII |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property3       |entityIII|2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyA       |entityW  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyB       |entityX  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyC       |entityY  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyD       |entityZ  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property1       |entityI  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property2       |entityII |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property3       |entityIII|2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyA       |entityW  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyB       |entityX  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyC       |entityY  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyD       |entityZ  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property1       |entityI  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property2       |entityII |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property3       |entityIII|2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyA       |entityW  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyB       |entityX  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyC       |entityY  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyD       |entityZ  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property1       |entityI  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property2       |entityII |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property3       |entityIII|2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyA       |entityW  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyB       |entityX  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyC       |entityY  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyD       |entityZ  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property1       |entityI  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property2       |entityII |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property3       |entityIII|2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyA       |entityW  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyB       |entityX  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyC       |entityY  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyD       |entityZ  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
+----------+----------------+---------+-------------------+
```